# Get the Max value from Ordered Result set without re-querying?

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-structures, database-performance

I am looking for a performance tuning opportunity, I know behind the scenes what I want is possible, but I do not know if SQL Server constructs support it. I want to return the TOP x records Ordered by an index, with an inequality offset. However I also want the min/max value from that query, without having to requery/resort the data.

Here is the script to setup the example

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Temp;

CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    RecordId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    TextField varchar(512) NOT NULL,
    InsertDate datetime NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #Temp (TextField, InsertDate)
SELECT Replicate('Text',n%128), GetDate()
FROM
    (SELECT TOP 100000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) n
        FROM sys.columns a
            cross join sys.columns b) as subquery

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_IX ON #Temp (RecordId);
```

Once the table is created, I want to run a query like this:

```
SELECT TOP 512 *
FROM #Temp
WHERE RecordId > 256
ORDER BY RecordID
```

*(This query results in 29 logical reads on my machine.)*

However I also what to know what the Max RecordId is from this query (assume there are gaps in RecordId and I cannot use addition). Since I know the max value was loaded into memory, it should be fairly easy to retrieve, but I cannot figure out to do with without re-querying the data:

```
SELECT MAX(RecordId)
    FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 512 *
        FROM #Temp
        WHERE RecordId > 256
     ORDER BY RecordID) as subquery
```

This virtually repeats the same execution plan as the previous query (another 29 logical reads for a total of 58). However, this is just to get one value which I already queried. Is there a way to accomplish all of this in one pass (29 logical reads total)?

Comment: I can't think of a way of doing this without first materializing the data somewhere.  So I agree with your current approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a common-table expression for your `top N` query.  Then the `max() over ()` window function can return the maximum from among the `top N`:

```
with    CTE as
        (
        select  top 512 *
        from    #Temp
        where   RecordID > 556
        order by
                RecordID
        )
select  *
,       max(RecordID) over () as MaxRecordID
from    CTE
```